# How to solve : $ \frac{\log(5x-6)}{\log(x)} = \log (x)$

Tags: logarithms

I'm struggling with this equation :

$$ \frac{\log(5x-6)}{\log(x)} = \log (x)$$

I've tried to do this:

$$ \log(5x-6) = \log^2(x)$$

But really I can' do more. . I just need a hint

Comment: Where is this equation coming from ? Are these natural logarithms ?

Comment: Yeah , base 10. .

Comment: You probably mean "Nay, base $10$".

Comment: Perhaps the LHS should be $\log((5x-6)/x)$?

Comment: Thanks for you repply @David . Are you saying are there a mistake in the equation ?

Comment: Was this the original problem?

Comment: @David. The problem is simply figure out the variable "x"

Comment: Ok, if that is the given equation, ignore my previous comment.

Comment: @David because you thought that I had make a mistake writting the equation ,aren't you ?

Comment: I thought this might have been a basic algebra level problem. The LHS looks like a missaplication of the quotient rule for logs

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to get escape of the logarithm to see what's going on.

Let $5x-6=e^t$,

$$t=\ln^2\left(\frac{e^t+6}{5}\right)$$

$$\sqrt t=\ln \left(\frac{e^t+6}{5}\right)$$

$$\frac{e^t+6}{5}=e^{\sqrt t}$$

$$e^t+6=5e^{\sqrt t}$$

Let $\sqrt t=u$,

$$5e^u-e^{u^2}-6=0$$

$$ \color {gold}{\boxed {\color{black} {e^{u^2}-5e^u+6=0.}}}$$

There is no standard mathematical function that can solve the last equation.

Comment: Thanks lone. So do you say that we not even could eliminate the logs funtions ?

Comment: Do you think there are a mistake in the equation ?

Comment: @NIN Yes most likely.

Comment: Really thank you lone

Comment: @NIN You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the zero of function $$f(x)=\log_{10}(5x-6) - \log_{10}^2(x)$$

This is smaller than
$$\log_{10}(5x) - \log_{10}^2(x)=\log_{10}(5)+\log_{10}(x) - \log_{10}^2(x)$$ To have an *estimate*, solve the quadratic equation in $\log_{10}(x)$. This gives
$$\log_{10}(x)\sim 1.47415\implies x\sim 10^{1.47415}\sim 29.7955$$ Now, use Newton method with this overestimate
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 29.795516 \\
 1 & 29.153010 \\
 2 & 29.156608
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Very interesting. Really thank you. How you deleted '6' in the first step ?

Comment: @NIN. I just say that there was a majorant equation since $5x-6 <5x \implies \log(5x-6)<\log(5x)=\log(5)+\log(x)$. This gives a good estimate to start with.

Comment: Really. Thank you. I was struggling with this.